# SSIS: Finding Table Used in Other Package(s)/ Integration

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I did see some other posts on this, but they were rather old and there does not appear to be any solutions at this point.

I'm trying to determine where a particular table(s) that SSIS is loading during a monthly job is being used in other packages. The package that loads these tables have in the past several months been taking much longer than before, and I'm trying to see if I can eliminate this load all together.

I just happened to check the Allocation packages in our database to see how the tables were being used, and discovered that I can't find anywhere when/where those tables are being used. Is there a function or query I can run in SSMS or elsewhere to determine how to find this information?

Thx in advance - please let me know if I need to clarify something.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2012, when you deploy a package, everything goes into a SSIS catalog database (SSISDB).  I've never tried it, but maybe you could pull the information you're looking for from it.

Answer (score 3):

The packages are just XML files. If you have the packages somewhere on your file system you can use any program that searches through text files.

I'm not sure about older SSIS projects but with an SSIS project in Data Tools for SQL Server 2012 you can just use the build in search function to search through your entire solution. It will also search in the XML of all the packages.

Comment: Thanks, JodyT!  I was able to look through the xml files and haven't found any instances. I just wanted to be sure there wasn't a more efficient way or in case I missed something.  We're not on 2012 yet, but I might have one of our developers check using their version.  Sounds like a handy tool/addition! = )

Comment: JodyT:  I did find out that using Notepad++ (great app!), I could open all packages/reports, and it has a function to search all open documents.  This completed the search very quickly, and it appears there are no other instances of these tables used in SSIS. Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have this particular information saved anywhere already in your documentation then I think you are going to have some difficulty in finding an accurate way to retrieve this information. However, there are a few automated data collection options that might help you get most of the way there.

The first option is that because all SSIS Packages are essentially glorified XML that is being fed into an engine you can perform a patterned search on the packages like GREP to look for that particular table name. Any packages that dynamically retrieve and build the table name though would not be found through this method.

Another option would be to run a server side SQL trace with a pattern match based on the table name(s) and limited to the host or application name of SSIS. Run over the course of a month or so would make for a fairly accurate list.

Comment: Thanks, David!  And yes, you're right - unfortunately, the documentation we have does not indicate anything about this particular package/table, which is why I'm somewhat frustrated.  However, if it turns out I don't find anything, I'll happily be able to disable this package from running in future loads! = )

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but the [DOC xPress](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/DOC-xPress/Features/SQLImpactAnalysis.aspx) tool from PragmaticWorks might be what you're looking for.